# How to change in use driver linux

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, gpu, radeon

I have "**radeon**" and "**amdgpu**" **drivers** installed. I want to **switch** to amdgpu from radeon but I don't know how can I do that.

lspci -v | grep driver:

```
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

lspci -v | grep modules:

```
Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

How can I switch to **amdgpu**? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommend method will depend on what Linux distribution you are running. But one thing that should work is to blacklist the radeon module from running.

In `/etc/modprobe.d`, create a new `.conf` file, and give it the following contents:

```
blacklist radeon
```

Comment: Okay I did it, I'm using ubuntu but it didn't switch to amdgpu, now running without gpu driver :D

Comment: @eminfedar, what distro are you running? can you post the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: Okay I solved it, problem is on **my kernel**, **not blacklist radeon** :) this method works.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this in for others who come across this; after blacklisting modules you have to update the kernel:

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Answer (score -1):

Use this command to unload a module:- 
rmmod modulename in your it will be rmmod radeon.

In order to check loaded module use :-
lsmod | grep modulename

### In order to prevent them from loading after reboot edit the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist (if you are using debian/ubuntu) and add the line

### blacklist driver-name

### In case of Fedora/Centos/Rhel. Edit file /etc/modprobe.conf and add the following line :-

### alias driver-name off